# API with Flask: hand parameter to blueprint based on URL (enforce url parameter for EVERY view)

Tags: python, flask, parameter-passing

I want to quickly set up an API as a draft and I found that Flask comes with the lightweight-ness I want.

However, being new to Flask, I am still not sure how to design my file layout to be nice and clear to be worked on with several contributors to over time flesh out the API.

So what I got so far is, that I need Blueprints to include my routes from other modules. That works like a charm. But now let's go for the tricky part.

Our Database is designed in a way, that we have the same tables for several languages.

The access for the API will be per language, so it does not really make sense to use the language as a parameter, and the language is important to determine on which tables we act. This is done on a per request basis.

Basically I want the API to look like this:

```
/v1.0/<language-code>/entries
/v1.0/<language-code>/sentences
```

*On a sidenote:
The routes for entries come from `v1/entries/access.py`.
(I take suggestions to pack the entities of my api into a better file structuring scheme)*

So how can I make sure my views (the function a route links to), knows which `language-code` was requested.

Is there a nice way of achieving it by making the parameter available globally in the app or something, or should I extract it from the requested url?

I am open for hacks, too! :3

// EDIT:
I found this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/urlprocessors/
which goes into the right direction, however, extracting the language-code and writing it to g, would still later on require me, to verify if the language is available.

I would like to verify if the language (that must be given) is valid, and if not return an error.

```
@app.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_lang_code(endpoint, values):
    // do some verification in here
    if values:
        g.lang_code = values.pop('lang_code', None)
```

So if the verification fails, respond with an error, if it does not fail, I can assume in all of my functions that lang-code exists somewhere (maybe in `g`) and is accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the way to go, but I stumbled across the `before_request` decorator, which seems to do what I want:

```
from flask import Flask, g, abort, jsonify, request
from v1.entries import access as entry_access

app = Flask(__name__)

# load the endpoints
PRE = "/v1.0/<lang_code>"
app.register_blueprint(entry_access.entries, url_prefix=PRE+"/entries")

@app.before_request
def verify_language():
    # check if there are any parameters in the url and get lang_code
    url_params = request.view_args
    lang = (url_params and url_params.pop('lang_code', None)) or None
    # if lang_code is given, make sure it is valid
    if lang:
        LANG = ["eng-code", "swe-code"]
        if lang in LANG or lang == "global":
            # set globally to provide access for all views
            g.lang = lang
        else:
            return jsonify({"error": "Invalid Parameters (lang_code)"})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get `language_code` as a argument of function.

```
blueprint = Blueprint('entries', __name__)

@blueprint.route('/v1.0/<language_code>/entries')
def get_entries(language_code):
    return jsonify({'result': "your language code is " + language_code})
```

name `language-code` is not allowed, parameter name should be valid python variable name.

Comment: The language-code is needed in every blueprint, that's why I kind of wanted to avoid putting the whole uri in the route and define the language somewhere in the main file that includes all blueprints, like with `url_prefix` for example. (and optimally check for correctness before routing, as the language codes have a certain scheme xx_xxx_xx)